# Using AutomationID with ListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I'm trying to attach an automationId to items within a listview.  Ideally by binding a project name to the item that is shown.

```
<ListView
ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
AutomationId="{Binding Projects}
HasUnevenRows="True"
IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

The code is deploying but not running when I get to the page, has anyone found a good workaround to bind the ID like that?

Long term, I want to use it with the Xamarin Forms ability to scroll which can scroll to a marked item, but not scroll to a displayed text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AutomationId` is not a bindable property as apparent in the Xamarin.Forms source code:

[**Xamarin.Forms.Core.Element.cs**](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Element.cs)

```
string _automationId;


public string AutomationId
{
    get { return _automationId; }
    set
    {
        if (_automationId != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("AutomationId may only be set one time");
        _automationId = value;
    }
}
```

This has been raised by several people on [Xamarins User Voice](https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/13865469-make-automationid-a-bindableproperty-in-xamarin-fo).

You'll need to hard code the `AutomationId` for the meantime and build your UI tests with a hard coded id in mind.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3845 have been fixed and merged to master. So you can expect that AutomationId will be a bindable property in the next version of Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 4):

I got around this by using an attached property as a proxy that I could bind to:

```
public class AutomationBinding
{
    #region AutomationId Attached Property
    public static readonly BindableProperty AutomationIdProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached
                                                                                   (nameof(AutomationIdProperty),
                                                                                    typeof(string),
                                                                                    typeof(AutomationBinding),
                                                                                    string.Empty,
                                                                                    propertyChanged: OnAutomationIdChanged);

    public static string GetAutomationId(BindableObject target)
    {
        return (string)target.GetValue(AutomationIdProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAutomationId(BindableObject target, string value)
    {
        target.SetValue(AutomationIdProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    static void OnAutomationIdChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        // Element has the AutomationId property
        var element = bindable as Element;
        string id = (newValue == null) ? "" : newValue.ToString();

        // we can only set the AutomationId once, so only set it when we have a reasonable value since
        // sometimes bindings will fire with null the first time
        if (element != null && element.AutomationId == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            element.AutomationId = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Which could then be used in xaml like so:

```
<Button local:AutomationBinding.AutomationId="{Binding}" Text="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: Definitely +1 for this! I had issues with setting it on some views that were a couple of levels down. Thank you!