# AutomationId in a Xamarin.Forms ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, appium, ui-automation

I am working on a project testing a Xamarin.Forms app with Appium and AutomationId seems to make elements available to Appium for selecting by their Id, as expected. My team is using a ListView for a data intensive section of the app and we are looking for a way to assign a unique identifier to each label where information will be populated and many of the answers I have found, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594476/using-automationid-with-listview), are rather old and also don't have a workable answer for me.

How would we go about making each text field in this ListView accessible by Appium for automated testing?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you have a `ListView` in application and all list have same id, in that case you can find those element by `Name` or `Xpath`.

```
driver.findElement(By.Name("YourText")).click();
or
driver.findElement(new By.ByName("YourText")).click();
or
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='YourText']")).click();
```